# Is there any possible way to solve this equation with two different variables with different degrees?

Tags: quadratics

$$649 + 96y = k^{2}$$
Also, $(y)$ or $(y + 1)$ or $(y-1)$ must be a perfect square.
$y$ and $k$ are both natural numbers.

Comment: Is this to be solved over the integers?  Saying a perfect square seems to imply it.  Write $y=m^2$ and similarly for the other two cases.

Answer (score 1):

I asked Alpha to solve $649+96x^2=y^2$ over the integers, then replaced $649$ with $553$ and $745$.  Only [$745$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20745%2B96x%5E2%3Dy%5E2%20over%20the%20integers) gave solutions.  The lowest is $x=8,y=83$ and there are a few families.  It clearly used the continued fraction approach to find them.  The usual approach to show there are no solutions is to find a clever modulus to show the equation is impossible.

Comment: Hey there, I actually had a doubt in solving a question on Quora. If you can, will you please check my answer here: https://www.quora.com/Three-numbers-in-AP-are-removed-from-first-n-natural-numbers-Mean-of-the-remaining-numbers-is-43-4-What-is-n-if-one-of-the-removed-numbers-is-a-perfect-square